# Forward delivery receipt in Outlook 2013

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2013, forwarding

I created a rule in Outlook to forward emails with a specific subject line. I also want delivery receipts to be forwarded by that rule, but they do not get forwarded. Is there an easy way to also forward these delivery receipts.

This is my current rule:

[image: Mails with the subject line "Zugestellt"(delivered) should be forwarded to mail@domain.com]

I have already found [this TechNet blog post](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/exchange/2011/02/23/everything-you-wanted-to-know-about-read-receipts-and-delivery-reports-but-were-understandably-afraid-to-ask/) regarding delivery receipts but this only deals with delivery report requests.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use rules for it. Use Outlook Options -> Mail -> Tracking -> **After updating tracking information, move receipts to**.

Comment: Can I also forward the delivery receipt to another user with this option?

Comment: You can, but you need to connect another user's mailbox to be able to select target folder.